# Should I keep design patterns terminologies?

Tags: oop, design-patterns

When I'm implementing design patterns, should I keep terms like "strategy", "visitor", "facade" or could I fit these names to the context of my application ? What is the best practice ?

Comment: You can check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222369/what-naming-convention-do-you-use-for-the-decorator-pattern

Comment: I think this is an opportunity to mention the AbstractSingeltonProxyFactoryBean! http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/aop/framework/AbstractSingletonProxyFactoryBean.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should always keep some reference to the pattern in your naming where it makes it meaningful and descriptive.

Patterns are a means of communication. If I come across code that is an XyzVisitor, I know that the visitor pattern has been used. With nothing else, the name has conveyed a whole stack of information on how the code works (or should work).

That said, sometimes it would just be a bit odd. Eg. DatabaseSingleton. Whereas AccountRefreshCommand fits quite nicely.

Comment: +1 for "Patterns are a means of communication"

Answer (score 5):

You should fit these names to the context of the application. It will make it easier for the people reading your code. You can add the patterns in your documentation.

Comment: Documentation? What's that?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on which pattern you're using, Some pattern names may be mixed with class names, e.g. I use

```
class LogFactory
class StudentsAdapter
```

for factory and adapter patterns, but

```
Engine.Instance
```

for singleton.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on whether you are happy renaming the class in the event of using a different pattern, for me it would smack too much of hungarian notation difficulties.